# Use value of variable instead of its name lambdas matlab

Tags: matlab, lambda

How to use value of variable instead of its name during the description of a lambda expression? This is part of my code:

```
eq1 = k*x1+b==y1;
eq2 = k*x2+b==y2;
sol=solve([eq1,eq2],[k,b]);
linEq1 = @(x) sol.k*x+sol.b;
if (defY<linEq1(defX))
    ineq = @(x,y) y<=sol.k*x+sol.b;
else
    ineq = @(x,y) y>=sol.k*x+sol.b;
end
```

I need to use value of `sol.b` and `sol.k` in lambda expression instead of their names. When I use function which contains this code I can see in workspace:

```
y<=sol.k*x+sol.b
```

instead of

```
y<=5x+3
```

for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to condense your code a bit. Please provide a *minimal working example* next time.

```
a = 5
b = 3
y = @(x) a*x + b % note that a and b are evaluated at definition

a = 4
y(1) % this is 8 (even though we changed the value of a)

% but if you really really want to do what you are asking, this is how: 
eval(['y = @(x) ' num2str(a) '*x + ' num2str(b)]) % yields y = @(x)4*x+3
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help and advice. This:
eval(['y = @(x) ' num2str(a) '*x + ' num2str(b)])  is exactly what i need.